# How to avoid indentation for cases in switch statement using C/C++ code formatter in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-cdt, indentation, formatter

I want the bodies of a case to be indent, but not the cases itself (when I have more than one).

Example:

My code looks like this:

```
switch(statement)
{
    case AAA:
    case BBB:
    case CCC:
        // do something
        break;
    case DDD:
    case EEE:
        // do something else
        break;
    default:
        // do something else
        break;
}
```

After I format my code by pressing Ctrl + Shift + f, the code looks like this:

```
switch(statement)
{
    case AAA:
        case BBB:
        case CCC:
        // do something
        break;
    case DDD:
        case EEE:
        // do something else
        break;
    default:
        // do something else
        break;
}
```

Since I want the bodies of the cases to be indent I activated the option "Statements within 'case' body" under "General -> C/C++ -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Indentation". So it makes kind of sense to me that the other cases are treated as part of the block of the first case and thus being indent.

Does anyone know how to avoid the indentation of the cases after the first case?

I tried several indentation options but could not find the one I need.